# Top margin doesn't work in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin

```
<div class="btns" id="btnHome">HOME</div>
<div class="btns" id="btnCon">CONTACT</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="gall"></div>
```

CSS

```
.btns{
    float:left;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
}
#gall{
    margin:25px 0 15px;  // this top margin doesn't work in IE8
    height:70px;
    border:thin solid red;
}
```

[here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bonaca/68myJ/8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known bug in IE8](http://www.inventpartners.com/ie8_margin_top_bug). There are several ways to fix it.

You can try to add `overflow:auto` to the clearing `<div>`

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68myJ/16/)

Comment: Thanks to everyOne. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add display:inline-block; and width how much you want hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="btns" id="btnHome">HOME</div>
<div class="btns" id="btnCon">CONTACT</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
&nbsp; <!-- Adding &nbsp; will solve problem -->
<div id="gall"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/68myJ/13/

```
<div class="btns" id="btnHome">HOME</div>
<div class="btns" id="btnCon">CONTACT</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="gall"></div>

.btns{
    float:left;
    padding:2px 10px 2px 10px;
}

#gall{
    margin:25px 0 15px !important;
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    display:block; /* can revert inline block when long list for IE8*/
    border:thin solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="btns" id="btnHome">HOME</div>
  <div class="btns" id="btnCon">CONTACT</div>
</div>


<div id="gall"></div>
​

#wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.btns{
    float:left;
    padding:2px 10px 2px 10px;
}

#gall{
    margin:25px 0 15px !important;
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    display:block; /* can revert inline block when long list for IE8*/
    border:thin solid red;
}
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68myJ/17/